# split up data with java split() make empty data of first array

Tags: java

DB has like this data for hashtag in string type

`#a#b#c#d#e`

with this data, I want split each tag

so I code this

```
 String tagToArray[] = output.getText("TAG", i).split("#");
```

but the result is

```
tagToArray[, a, b, c, d, e]
```

I want to remove first empty data
what is the right way to splay data of hashtag?

Comment: Add a `.subtring(1)` before your `split("#")`.

Comment: You could also filter out the empty result(s) from `split()` if that is what is wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extra empty string produce for first `#`.

So, you can replace the first character if it is `#` then split.

```
 String tagToArray[] = output.getText("TAG", i).replaceFirst("^#", "").split("#");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first # before splitting

```
 String[] array = str.replaceFirst("#", "").split("#");
```

Comment: Will it work if the input is a#b#c#d#e? If the given text always begins with # then this work.

Comment: @NKR As I interpret the question the syntax is #value for each column

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be solved with the regex `(?<=\#)(.)`

Code:

```java
output.getText("TAG", i).split("(?<=\#)(.)");
```